# How can I get the value of a widget in the click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I met a problem, the code like this:

```
<img id = "ID" value = "Something" src = "images.gif"/>
```

Then I bind a click function to this image:

```
$("#ID").bind('click', function(){
    //Some manipulations here......
    //so, how can I get the value here?
    //which I mean, how can I get "Something" here?
});
```

Thank you!

I use 1.8 version of jQuery, sorry my score is not enough to add an comment to you!

Comment: Images don't have value attributes. Form elements do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<img id = "ID" data-value = "Something" src = "images.gif"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#ID").on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).data('value')); //will alert "Something"
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rLhN/)

I've moved "Something" into `data-value` because `img` is not a form element and therefor `value` is not valid for `img` tags. Also, I used `on()` instead of `bind()`:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

---

That being said... if you are unable to change the HTML for whatever reason, you can do this:

```
$("#ID").on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value')); // will alert "Something"
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kufp2/)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, and I will pay attention to use on() in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is odd (image tags do not have value attributes). Let's get the src instead  -

```
$("#ID").bind('click', function(){
    var myVariable = $(this).attr('src'); // myVariable is now 'images.gif'
});
```

Comment: I know - wasn't sure if the OP needed the basics, or something else.